# How can I use NULL in this situation?

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class 'Vector' which stores x,y,z values. I have a class ' which has multiple objects of 'Vector'.

```
Camera::Camera(Vector Pos, Vector LookAt, Vector UpDir)
{
}
Camera Cam(Vector(3,3,3), Vector(0,0,0), Vector(0,0,0));
```

Sometimes I don't want to pass Vector(0,0,0), I'd prefer to pass NULL and test if LookAt/UpDir == NULL or not but NULL doesn't want to work in this situation.
What should I do?

Hope this makes sense

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: Provide default values to the parameters and than you won't have to remember to pass (0,0,0) explicitly.

Comment: What is the motivation?  Are you trying to save some typing?  Are you concerned about clarity?  Are you concerned about performance?

Comment: Do you really want to have NULL or something like NULL_VECTOR would be ok?

Comment: Note: `NULL` is not "proper" C++, it's C. Use `nullptr` instead (or `0` if you have too old compiler which does not have `nullptr`).

Comment: C++ has overloads. What's wrong with `Camera::Camera(Vector Pos)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a static member named null.

```
class Camera {
  static Vector Null;
}

Vector Null(0,0,0);
```

Then use it when you need to compare.

```
if(my_vector == Camera::Null){
}
```

If find this always to be the most idiomatic approach.

Comment: That should probably be `static Vector Null;`

Comment: Or `Empty` or `Normal` or anything but `Null` as this has specific connotations to programers.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a default constructor for Vector and provide the ability for Vector to know that it is empty.  If the criteria for an empty Vector change from containing three zeroes to another number or something completely different then you can modify the empty() function to handle those conditions without modification to Camera.

```
Camera::Camera(Vector Pos, Vector LookAt, Vector UpDir)
{
  if(LookAt.empty()) 
  { 
    //do something; 
  }
}

Camera Cam(Vector(3,3,3), Vector(), Vector());
```

A concern with a static member of Camera initialized to three zeroes is the dependencies it will introduce into other classes that also need to check if a Vector is NULL.  They will need to include the Camera header file to access the declaration.  To me, it makes Vector dependent on Camera to define the NULL criteria instead of the other way around which I think might be problematic to maintain.

I am inspired to write this after reading about dependency breaking techniques in Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers.

Answer (score 0):

If possible change your interface to pointer of vector.

```
Camera::Camera(Vector *Pos, Vector *LookAt, Vector *UpDir)
{
}
```

And call it with the address of your vectors;

```
Camera Cam(&v1, &v2, NULL);
```

Comment: Don't do that. Now we need to start worrying about ownership. Which leads to all sorts of problems especially with beginners. Until you understand the concept of ownership very firmly stick with values rather than pointers (pointers should be wrapped in smart pointers to control lifespan and specify ownership semantics). This is not C.

Comment: This starts by assuming you _have_ the address of those vectors. I.e. the preferred format in the question (`Camera Cam(Vector(3,3,3), NULL, NULL)` breaks because you can't take the address of the first temporary.

Answer (score 0):

If your `Vector` object can have invalid state, you can use the following approach:

```
class Vector
{
public:
   int x, y, z;
   bool valid;

   Vector() : x(0), y(0), z(0), valid(false) {}
   Vector(int x, int y, int z) : x(x), y(y), z(z), valid(true) {}
};
```

Then your `Camera` class:

```
class Camera
{
public:
    Camera(const Vector &pos, const Vector &lookAt, const Vector &upDir)
    {
        if (!lookAt.valid) {...}
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
Camera c(Vector(1,2,3), Vector(), Vector());
```

You can define a static instance for default values:

```
class Vector
{
public:
    static Vector INVALID;
private: Vector(); // make invalid constructor private
};

Vector Vector::IVALID;
```

Usage:

```
Camera c(Vector(123), Vector::INVALID, Vector(12,4,5));
```